# Create multiple html files using Placeholders from Excel Rows

Tags: php, html, excel

I would like to create multiple HTML files from each row of an Excel spreadsheet

**EXCEL Spreadsheet:**

```
+-------+----------------+--------------+
|  Name |      Phone     | Description  |
+-------+----------------+--------------+
| James | 01234 5678910  | Text         |
| Clare | 16771 9432772  | Text         |
| Mike  | 08001 7745396  | Text         |
+-------+----------------+--------------+
```

I have created a "template" HTML file which has placeholders included such as:

```
    <div style="width:100%">

    {name}
    {phone}
    {description}

    </div>
```

I would like to use the Name column as the filename, and save each cell of that row into the placeholder in the HTML template.

Once the code has been executed this should create files called "James.html", "Clare.html", "Mike.html" etc... with the content in the {placeholder} sections.

I tried to attempt this using a CSV file but it didn't work.... here is my CSV / PHP code:

```
<?
$base_template = file_get_contents('/template.html');
$file_to_read = '/sample.csv';

ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", 1); 
$filename = '';

if (($handle = fopen($file_to_read, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $name = $data[0];
        $address = $data[1];
        $description = $data[2];

        $filename = preg_replace('/[\s\W]+/','',$name);
        $filename =  substr($filename, 0, 10);

        $template = str_replace('{name}', $name, $base_template);
        $template = str_replace('{phone}', $phone, $template);
$template = str_replace('{description}', $description, $template);

        $file = fopen('/save/'.$filename.'.html',"w+");
        fwrite($file, $template);   
        fclose($file);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

If anyone has any suggestions that would be great! Thank you

Comment: Without knowing what error you are getting I'm going to assume your webserver is not actually able to read and write to / and /save/ . Try using the full paths.